# How to customise ZXingDefaultOverlay in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have added `ZXingDefaultOverlay`, for scanning view.

my code is

```
<Forms:ZXingDefaultOverlay Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
```

[image]

as the image above it is adding a black color mask on scanner view.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this by creating `CustomOverlay` by inheriting `ZXingDefaultOverlay`

my code is

```
public class CustomOverlay : ZXingDefaultOverlay
    {
        public CustomOverlay()
        {
            foreach (var child in Children.OfType<BoxView>())
            {
                if (child == Children[2])
                {
                    child.BackgroundColor = StatusColorPalette.Success;
                    Margin = new Thickness(50, 0);
                }

                else
                {
                    child.Opacity = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

in Xamal use this

```
<Scan:CustomOverlay Grid.Row="1"/>
```

likewise we can customise the overlay.